# iOS how to change rootViewController when dismissController

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

my storyboard

If user doesn't login, the rootViewController is `Login`

after user login done, rootViewController is MainTabBarController

I have done that

But, I have encounter question is `Logout`

My `Logout` is dismissViewController

If my rootViewController is `Login`, it works

It will remove current ViewController, so `Login` appear

But when my rootViewController is `MainTabBarController`, dismiss is not work, I've try using `poptoRootViewController` in vain.

what should I do in `Logout` ?

I want to do like this

```
dismissController(true,{
   rootViewController = `Login`
})
```

Comment: Better after logout get the appDelegate.window.rootViewController and set it to LoginViewController

Comment: Why don’t you use unwind segue?

Answer (score 5):

For Logout do following:- (Add below code inside IBAction or didSelect ..etc method where logout is called)

```
// Making Login as rootViewController as user is no longer logged in
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()


                let loginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Login") as! loginViewController

                let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

                appDel.window?.rootViewController = loginVC
```

Also add following in AppDelegate:-

```
// Checking user login status, if user already logged in then making main tab bar view controller as root view controller 
           let userLoginStatus = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isUserLoggedIn")

            if(userLoginStatus)
            {

                let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                   let centerVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainTabBar") as! ViewController
            window!.rootViewController = centerVC
            window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
```

And Also where login Validation is done, after validating user credentials:-

```
 @IBAction func loginTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
   let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let centerVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainTabBar") as! ViewController
// Important to set status to true
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
appDel.window!.rootViewController = centerVC
        appDel.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

**NOTE:-** Don't forget to add STORYBOARD IDs for required View Controllers to instiantiate them

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make a function in AppDelegate and call that function on logout.

eg.(Obj-C Version)

```
- (void) setCurrentRootController : (UIViewController *)viewController {

    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window] setRootViewController:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window] setRootViewController:navigation];
}
```

When you are doing logout you just need to set rootViewController and then  call popToRootViewController method.

Hope this will work for you !!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any additional technics to set rootViewController in runtime except following:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController;
```

You can wrap this with animation if you want

Answer (score 0):

In Swift You can do like this

```
let vc: UIViewController! = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController")

    let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[0];
    window.rootViewController = vc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain two windows, one is for login, and second one for the users who got authenticated.

This way you can easily switch btw windows rather than having a messy MVC for it.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning, make sure your are** in the main thread if you use Delegate or Completion methods.

Code in Swift 3

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let tb = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoggedUser") as? UITabBarController else {
            print("Could not instantiate view controller with identifier of type LoggedUser")
            return
        }
        self.present(tb, animated: true, completion: nil)}
```