# Choosing viewcontroller behind tab bar item conditionally

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am having trouble understanding how I can choose which view controller is behind a tab bar item. So I have a tab bar controller as the root view of my application. This tab bar contains 4 items one of which is an "Account" tab. The thing I want to accomplish is if a user is logged in it will send him to an account overview view controller but when he's not logged in he will get a screen to log in.

So the architecture needs to be the same in either way. I want to start with the same screen (my tab bar controller) but only if the user taps on the account tab it needs to choose between 2 view controllers.

Is this possible? If yes, can someone please explain this concept to me?

Thank you for the help!

Kind regards

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782001/ios-how-to-change-rootviewcontroller-when-dismisscontroller/37782684#37782684 this might help you

Comment: But I still want to start with the same screen. I only wan't one of the viewcontroller to depend on if the user is logged in or not?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the root controller to your tab controller to login viewcontroller like this when user not able to login he will redirect to signinviewController

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("controllerIdentifiersetonvStroyboard") as SignViewController  
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = vc
```

Comment: But I still want to start with the same screen. I only wan't one of the viewcontroller to depend on if the user is logged in or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController,
                      shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool{
    let index = tabBarController.viewControllers?.index(of: viewController)
    if index == 2{ // Index of Account tab
        let userLoginStatus = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isUserLoggedIn")

        if !(userLoginStatus)
        {
            let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let loginVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Login") as! LoginViewController
            window!.rootViewController = loginVC
            window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
    return true// you decide
}
```

**NOTE**: shouldSelect delegate method can be used to achieve the desire result.

**Link**: - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate/1621166-tabbarcontroller?language=objc

Comment: Thank you! What is the best place to put this if I may ask?

Comment: Inside your UITabBarController class

Comment: Ok, so I implemented the code but it doesn't do anything yet. What should the value of "window" be? Now I declare it as "var window: UIWindow?". Is that correct? thanks!

Comment: AppDelegate.window